# Liquibase migration exception in Jhipster

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jhipster, liquibase, spring-cloud-stream

I have a JHipster project with two microservices and a gateway. Both were generated through JHipster. I am trying to send an object from `Projects` Microservice with `Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka` to ChargeCodes microservice. For this, I added [Spring Cloud Stream code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-core-docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-stream-overview.adoc) in ProjectResource.java file. Based on my requirement, Whenever new project object created, Spring Cloud Stream should send it to Kafka topic and Kafka consumer in the second microservice consumes it. To make it simple ,I created producer and consumer in the same project. When I compile the microservice I get following exception.

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180205173557_added_entity_Address.xml::20180205173557-1::jhipster:
```

My standslone [Spring boot Rest API app](https://github.com/jpavanaryan/SpringCloudStream-Kafka) with Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka works fine without any issues. I am not sure what's wrong with JHipster code. Code uploaded in [github repository](https://github.com/jpavanaryan/SpringCloudStream-Kafka-Docker).

ProjectResource.Java

```
package com.projects.web.rest;

import com.codahale.metrics.annotation.Timed;
import com.projects.domain.Project;
import com.projects.messaging.Greeting;
import com.projects.repository.ProjectRepository;
import com.projects.web.rest.errors.BadRequestAlertException;
import com.projects.web.rest.util.HeaderUtil;
import com.projects.web.rest.util.PaginationUtil;
import io.github.jhipster.web.util.ResponseUtil;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * REST controller for managing Project.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class ProjectResource
{

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "project";

    private final ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Source source;


    public ProjectResource(ProjectRepository projectRepository)
    {
        this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
    }


    /**
     * POST /projects : Create a new project.
     *
     * @param project
     *            the project to create
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 201 (Created) and with body the new
     *         project, or with status 400 (Bad Request) if the project has already
     *         an ID
     * @throws URISyntaxException
     *             if the Location URI syntax is incorrect
     */
    @PostMapping("/projects")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Project> createProject(@Valid @RequestBody Project project) throws URISyntaxException
    {
        log.debug("REST request to save Project : {}", project);
        if (project.getId() != null)
        {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new project cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        Project result = projectRepository.save(project);
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(result).build());
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/projects/" + result.getId()))
                .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString())).body(result);
    }

    /**
     * PUT /projects : Updates an existing project.
     *
     * @param project
     *            the project to update
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the updated
     *         project, or with status 400 (Bad Request) if the project is not
     *         valid, or with status 500 (Internal Server Error) if the project
     *         couldn't be updated
     * @throws URISyntaxException
     *             if the Location URI syntax is incorrect
     */
    @PutMapping("/projects")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Project> updateProject(@Valid @RequestBody Project project) throws URISyntaxException
    {
        log.debug("REST request to update Project : {}", project);
        if (project.getId() == null)
        {
            return createProject(project);
        }
        Project result = projectRepository.save(project);
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(result).build());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(ENTITY_NAME, project.getId().toString()))
                .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * GET /projects : get all the projects.
     *
     * @param pageable
     *            the pagination information
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of projects in
     *         body
     */
    @GetMapping("/projects")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<Project>> getAllProjects(Pageable pageable)
    {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Projects");
        Page<Project> page = projectRepository.findAll(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/projects");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * GET /projects/:id : get the "id" project.
     *
     * @param id
     *            the id of the project to retrieve
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the project, or
     *         with status 404 (Not Found)
     */
    @GetMapping("/projects/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Project> getProject(@PathVariable Long id)
    {
        log.debug("REST request to get Project : {}", id);
        Project project = projectRepository.findOne(id);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(project));
    }

    /**
     * DELETE /projects/:id : delete the "id" project.
     *
     * @param id
     *            the id of the project to delete
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK)
     */
    @DeleteMapping("/projects/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteProject(@PathVariable Long id)
    {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Project : {}", id);
        projectRepository.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(ENTITY_NAME, id.toString())).build();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
projects-app_1       | 2018-02-06 18:56:24.704 ERROR 6 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20180205173557_added_entity_Address.xml::20180205173557-1::jhipster: Change Set config/liquibase/changelog/20180205173557_added_entity_Address.xml::20180205173557-1::jhipster failed.  Error: Table 'address' already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE projects.address (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, street_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, apartment_or_house_number VARCHAR(255) NULL, city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, zipcode BIGINT NOT NULL, state VARCHAR(255) NULL, country VARCHAR(255) NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_ADDRESS PRIMARY KEY (id))]
projects-app_1       | 2018-02-06 18:56:24.829  WARN 6 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/projects/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180205173557_added_entity_Address.xml::20180205173557-1::jhipster:
projects-app_1       |      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'address' already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE projects.address (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, street_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, apartment_or_house_number VARCHAR(255) NULL, city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, zipcode BIGINT NOT NULL, state VARCHAR(255) NULL, country VARCHAR(255) NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_ADDRESS PRIMARY KEY (id))]
projects-app_1       | 2018-02-06 18:56:25.380 ERROR 6 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
projects-app_1       | 
projects-app_1       | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/projects/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180205173557_added_entity_Address.xml::20180205173557-1::jhipster:
projects-app_1       |      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'address' already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE projects.address (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, street_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, apartment_or_house_number VARCHAR(255) NULL, city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, zipcode BIGINT NOT NULL, state VARCHAR(255) NULL, country VARCHAR(255) NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_ADDRESS PRIMARY KEY (id))]
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
projects-app_1       |  at com.projects.ProjectsApp.main(ProjectsApp.java:68)
projects-app_1       |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
projects-app_1       |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
projects-app_1       |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
projects-app_1       |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
projects-app_1       | Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180205173557_added_entity_Address.xml::20180205173557-1::jhipster:
projects-app_1       |      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'address' already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE projects.address (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, street_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, apartment_or_house_number VARCHAR(255) NULL, city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, zipcode BIGINT NOT NULL, state VARCHAR(255) NULL, country VARCHAR(255) NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_ADDRESS PRIMARY KEY (id))]
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
projects-app_1       |  at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
projects-app_1       |  at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:84)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
projects-app_1       |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
projects-app_1       |  ... 24 common frames omitted
projects-app_1       | Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'address' already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE projects.address (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, street_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, apartment_or_house_number VARCHAR(255) NULL, city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, zipcode BIGINT NOT NULL, state VARCHAR(255) NULL, country VARCHAR(255) NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_ADDRESS PRIMARY KEY (id))]
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:309)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
projects-app_1       |  ... 34 common frames omitted
projects-app_1       | Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'address' already exists
projects-app_1       |  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
projects-app_1       |  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
projects-app_1       |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
projects-app_1       |  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2441)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
projects-app_1       |  at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
projects-app_1       |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
projects-app_1       |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
projects-app_1       |  at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:307)
projects-app_1       |  ... 39 common frames omitted
projects-app_1       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a first glance it appears that something caused one or more rows in DATABASECHANGELOG to be deleted, so Liquibase things that the changeset to create the table projects.address gets run again, but the table already exists.

Comment: If you look at schema or changelog. Nothing changed. Is this the right approach to modify the Rest API?

Comment: I understood the issue. When we change REST API code, JHipster thinks of it as database change. I implemented DTO with Service layer then sent an object from there. It works fine.